# Are these "slide-in" interchangeable plug adapters standardized/generic?

Tags: power-supply, adapter, terminology, standards, ac-adapter

I'm sure I have or had at least one other device with this handy feature, but here's a photo of my Lenovo netbook's wall-wart power supply with the Australian slide-in adapter plug detached.

[image: Lenovo switching adapter with Australian slide-in plug]

This is a great design. I travel overseas a lot so it would be very handy if I could pick up some of the other slide-in adapter plugs that are suitable to various countries.

Right now I'm in Taiwan and I've looked at main electronics market plus a consumer electronics outlets but so far without luck.

Of course I don't even know if they have a set name that everybody uses to describe them even in English, let alone Chinese.

I'll be in China again soon enough so I expect I'll at least be able to get a friend to order a Lenovo one online.

But I'm sure I'm not the only one who has wondered about these things so it would be great to have a answer online that can help everybody and not just me.

Comment: I doubt that the adapter plates are standardized.  I have some [Phihong power modules](http://www.mouser.com/new/phihong/phihongpsa15r/) that use a [similar interchangeable plug plate](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Phihong/RPS-N-R/?qs=%2fha2pyFadujf5qmeJdbRr%252b0VUKGRwDpNMy3q5S73tHA%3d), and it looks different from your picture.

Comment: Well that's disappointing, unsurprising, and great to know one way or the other. I notice they use the term "clip" for the replaceable part but no special term for the other part other than "... with interchangeable clips". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to assume no.  While they would be standardized for that adapter's model, by the OEM (Lenovo and others purchase these from a 3rd party).  There is no guarantee they get the same model every time, or even from the same manufacturer.

You can see the actual manufacturer at the bottom, Shenzen Honor Electronics.  If you can find parts from them for the same model, then it *should* work.